# Phantom scrollbar-sized margin in chrome extension browser action popup

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I have a browser action popup that, whenever I make content large enough to produce a scrollbar, gets a margin equal to the width of the scrollbar. This means if I change the width of `::-webkit-scrollbar`, the size of the margin changes.

Interestingly, this will only happen if I set an explicit width on an element. So, if I set `html` to have `width: 400px`, it will get the margin. If set an `li` to have `width: 400px`, it will get the margin. I've tried setting `* { margin: 0 !important }`, but even that doesn't fix the problem. The only solution I can find is setting a negative margin.

Even crazier, looking at the computed styles of `html`, there is no margin.

[image]

How can I remove this margin? The best solution I can find is setting a negative `margin-right` equal to the width of the scrollbar via Javascript, but that's a bit inelegant. Is there a CSS-only solution?

Here's an example of how it looks with a bunch of `<li>`s.

[image]

Comment: See https://crbug.com/821143. Try  
html {
  overflow: overlay;
}

Comment: Nice workaround. If you make this an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Did you have this problem in Firefox as well? I do, and the overlay workaround isn't fixing it there.

Comment: Upon further research, `overlay` wouldn't work because it's not supported in Firefox, and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1395025 is a bug that seems to document the problem.